# How to write fields many2one in Odoo with XMLRPC

Tags: mapping, field, odoo, xml-rpc, many-to-one

I want to use the xmlrpc for the model "product.category".

How to write the field "categ_id" with "read and search"in PYTHON ? I have always an error. I need to do that because i have to transfer this informations into another database Odoo.

```py
    import xmlrpc.client
    import time
    url_db1="http://localhost:8069"
    db_1='DB_ONE'
    username_db_1='username'
    password_db_1='password'

    common_1 = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url_db1))
    models_1 = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url_db1))
    version_db1 = common_1.version()

    print("details..", version_db1)


    url_db2="http://localhost:806972"
    db_2='DB_2'
    username_db_2='myemail'
    password_db_2='mypassword'

    common_2 = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url_db2))
    models_2 = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url_db2))
    version_db2 = common_2.version()

    print("details..", version_db2)


    uid_db1 = common_1.authenticate(db_1, username_db_1, password_db_1, {})
    uid_db2 = common_2.authenticate(db_2, username_db_2, password_db_2, {})

    db_1_categories = models_1.execute_kw(db_1, uid_db1, password_db_1, 'product.category', 'search_read', [[]], {'fields':['id','name', 'parent_id']})

    total_count = 0
    for category in db_1_categories:
        print("category..", category)
        total_count +=1
        values = {}
        values['id'] = category['id']
        values['name'] = category['name']
        if category['parent_id']:
            values['parent_id'] = category['parent_id'][0]
        new_lead = models_2.execute_kw(db_2, uid_db2, password_db_2, 'product.category', 'create', [values])
print("Total Created..", total_count)
```

This is the error :
ValidationError: ('The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.\n\nModel: Product Category (product.category), Constraint: product_category_parent_id_fkey', None)\n'>

[image]

Comment: Hi, i'm just wondering where those questions nowadays come from? The external API has its own section in [Odoo's documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html) (v13) where your question is [answered already](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html#search-and-read).

Comment: Hi @CZoellner, yes, i read the documentation, but i need to transfer the categ_id from a database Odoo to another database like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054256/xml-rpc-transfering-field-many2one-between-two-databases-odoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method name should be [search_read](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html#search-and-read)

***Example***:

```py
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
   'product.template', 'search_read',
    [],
    {'fields': ['name', 'default_code', 'categ_id']})
```

It should return a list of dicts, the `categ_id` field value is a list of two values, the first is the id of the category and the second is the name of the category.

To [write](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html#update-records) `categ_id`, you just need to provide the category ID to the write method.

***Example:***

```py
product_template_data = [{'default_code': 'FURN_6666', 'categ_id': [8, 'All / Saleable / Office Furniture'], 'id': 23, 'name': 'Acoustic Bloc Screens'}, ...] 

for ptd in product_template_data:
    models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'write', 
        [[ptd['id']], 
        {
            'categ_id': ptd['categ_id'][0],
            ...
        }
    ])
```

You mentioned that you need to transfer data to another database, the product template is probably not present which means that you can't call the write method instead, you can call the [create](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html#create-records) method.

***Example:***

```py
id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'create', [{
    'categ_id': ptd['categ_id'][0],
    ...
}])
```

***Edit:***
You will get an invalid syntax error using:

```py
[product,'categ_id': product['categ_id'][0],]
```

To pass values to the create method, you need to pass `args` to the `execute_kw` method as a list then pass values as a dictionary inside that list.

***Edit:***

```py
values = {}
values['name'] = product['name']
values['categ_id'] = product['categ_id'][0]
...
new_lead = models_2.execute_kw(db_2, uid_db2, password_db_2, 'product.template', 'create', [values])
```

***Edit: Use the parent category id in the new database***

When we call the create method it will create a new record and return its `ID` which is probably different the one passed through the `values` dictionary.

To avoid the `ValidationError` you can use a dictionary where the parent ID in the old database is the key and the new ID is the value then you have just to pass that value when creating a new category.

```py
category_ids = {}
for category in db_1_categories:
        print("category..", category)
        total_count +=1
        values = {}
        # values['id'] = category['id']
        values['name'] = category['name']
        if category['parent_id']:
            values['parent_id'] = category_ids[category['parent_id'][0]]
        category_id = models_2.execute_kw(db_2, uid_db2, password_db_2, 'product.category', 'create', [values])
        category_ids[category['id']] = category_id
```

Comment: Nice answer, but i wouldn't recommend to create a template at the end. Usually you already should have a "external template ID" anywhere in the first Odoo, so you should know about the "other Odoo's" template.

Comment: @Kenly Thank you, your explanation is very detailed but it doesn't work. I updated my question and putted the code to show you. I need to transfer the field "categ_id" between 2databases Odoo. I tried your solution but still have an error.

Comment: @Kenly the function "read and search" works, but in the creating, it blocks.

Comment: Hi @Kenly, you're very a good person, i will try your solution and tell you :D

Comment: Hi @Kenly, sorry for the late, i had an error and tried to correct it before i show you anything, but what ever i tried, it's always the same error. I really did what you told me... i will update my post to see your my code and the error...

Comment: The specified `categ_id` should be present in `DB_2` with the same `id`, try first to create categories before creating product templates.

Comment: Yes @Kenly, good idea ! I did the same thing for the product.category, i changed this "values['parent_id'] = product['parent_id'][0]" but i have this error: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable , how to correct it please? :$

Comment: Check if the category parent exists and if yes add it to `values`. Parent categories may have `parent_id` field set to `False`

Comment: Oh @Kenly, i think it's a big progress, the program run correctly and it displays all the categories with their parent_id but in Odoo, i don't see the parent_id, only the name of categories... i will add screenshot in my post and update the code (thank you for all your efforts)

Comment: `if 'parent_id' in values` will always be evaluated to `False` and the parent category will never be passed through values, try to use `if category['parent_id']`. Parent categories should be created first, so make sure to get the result ordered by `id`.

Comment: I tried your solution @Kenly : "if category ['parent_id'] in values:" i had this error message : "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: when i did researches in the net, i found that i have to use "Tuple", so i did this :"  if  (tuple(category ['parent_id'])) in values "

Comment: and now i have this error " TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable " it's a bit difficult ... sorry, i really try to search a solution

Comment: You have just to replace `if 'parent_id' in values` with `if category['parent_id']:`, the values dict has no `parent_id` yet so the first statement will be evaluated to false and my solution is to check if the parent category is set for the current category using `if category['parent_id']:` without checking the values dict.

Comment: Thank you Kenly, I understand better, the result gave me an error too :

Comment: ValidationError: (\'The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted.

Comment: If possible, archive it instead.\\n\\nModel: Product Category (product.category), Constraint: product_category_parent_id_fkey\', None)\n'>

Comment: Hi @Kenly, not really but i will  not give up ! è_é

Comment: I updated the code @Kenly, but you know, my modification is only the one line that you told me to add: "    if category ['parent_id']:
        values['parent_id'] = category['parent_id'][0]"

Comment: The `id` passed through the values dictionary is not used as the new category id. Check my edit.

Comment: Good morning @Kenly, I think that i have taking the habit to talk to you hahaha Thank you so much, it works !!!! You're a genius of python and Odoo, i will never forget. I hope for you a wonderful life with good health and a lot of money :)

Comment: You as well. Thank you, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Kenly Hi, how are you today ? It's me again hahaha... :x Iam a little shamed but i will continue my comment : I have a question about your code because i tried to applicate it with another model and it doesn't work. So my question is :

Comment: Why did you put this line in the end: "category_ids[category['id']] = category_id" in the end? , i have understood this : "if category['parent_id']:
   values['parent_id'] = category_ids[category['parent_id'][0]]" but not the ending line. Can you explain me please ?

Comment: I used that line to map the old id to the new one. When a category has a parent category we need to get the parent id in the new database using the parent id in the old database, so each time we create a new category we need to save its id using the old id as a key to get its value later. When we call the ``search_read``, the parent categories appear before their child categories in the result list.

Comment: I think that i understand, thank you... Could this also apply to all many2one fields? or does it only concern parent categories?

Comment: When you create a new record its id is probably different in the new database and yes it applies for any many2one fields.

Comment: I will review my work :$ thank you, sorry if i bothered you. Can i contact you by e-mail?

Comment: No problem, you can email me at kenlylast@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219500/discussion-between-julie-losange-and-kenly).

Answer (score 0):

first of all error in your code

### This is your code

db_1_products = models_1.execute_kw(db_1, uid_db1, password_db_1, 'product.template', 'search_read', [[]], {'fields':['id','name', 'categ_id','type', 'default_code', 'list_price', 'website_url', 'inventory_availibility', 'website_description']})

```
total_count = 0
for product in db_1_products:
    print("produt..", product)
    total_count +=1
    new_lead = models_2.execute_kw(db_2, uid_db2, password_db_2, 'product.template', 'create', [product,'categ_id': product['categ_id'][0],])
```

print("Total Created..", total_count)

### This is updated code

db_1_products = models_1.execute_kw(db_1, uid_db1, password_db_1, 'product.template', 'search_read', [[]], {'fields':['id','name', 'categ_id','type', 'default_code', 'list_price', 'website_url', 'inventory_availibility', 'website_description']})

```
total_count = 0
for product in db_1_products:
    print("produt..", product)
    total_count +=1
    new_lead = models_2.execute_kw(db_2, uid_db2, password_db_2, 'product.template', 'create', [{product,'categ_id': product['categ_id'][0]}])
```

print("Total Created..", total_count)

you need to pass dictionary when creating of any model in odoo.

Comment: Hi @patel, thank's for your reponse, but it's not that, please see the reponse of Kenly, his solution works